# Making HTTP POST request in Qt with Meego 1.2 Harmattan

Tags: qt, http, post, meego

Here's the situation - I attach some file (JPEG image) to the HTTP POST request so it should be sent to the local server via Wi-Fi and server should return some result (simple text).

Here's the problem I faced doing this in my Qt-application for Nokia N9 (Meego 1.2 Harmattan).
After request is sent, proceed by the server and answer is sent back (I can see log on the server) there's a **huge delay (about 1 min) before data from server reaches the handset**.
If answer returns in several parts - the delay is before first part and others are getting very fast (as it should be with the first one too).

The *same* code I use in the same app for Symbian^3 (Symbian Anna) on Nokia C6-01 and it works just fine - all the data returns in a couple of seconds (tested in the *same* network with the *same* server and request). Also I have several GET requests sending from this app to the same server and all of them works fine too. So it might be the only Meego problem.

Snippets:

```
void PostDownloader::sendPostJpgImage(QString url, QImage image) {
        if(mainReply)
        return;

    char boundary[] = "AyV04a234DsHeKHcvNds";

    image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);

    QByteArray body;
    QBuffer buffer(&body);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    image.save(&buffer, "JPG");
    buffer.close();

    QByteArray b;
    b.append("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
    b.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jpgfile\"; filename=\"camera\"\r\n");
    b.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
    b.append("\r\n");
    b.append(body);
    b.append("\r\n");
    b.append("--").append(boundary).append("--");

    QNetworkRequest req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url));
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant(QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=")+boundary));
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QString::number(b.size()));
    req.setRawHeader("Connection", "Close");
    req.setRawHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    req.setRawHeader("Keep-Alive", "1");
    mainReply = manager->post(req, b); //POST

    connect(mainReply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(dataReceived()));
    connect(mainReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finished()));
}
```

So the delay is before calling the dataReceived() slot. How can this can be solved? What can you advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try without the `Connection` and `Keep-Alive` headers ? If you don't set the `Connection` header explicitly, `QNetworkAccessManager` sets it by default to "keep-alive" anyways.

Comment: This headers were added later when I was trying to fix the bug. So without them this problem stays the same